# Integrating editable comboBox and spin entries inside Treeview cell

Tags: c, eclipse, gtk, eclipse-cdt, glade

I want to integrate editable ComboBoxes and Spin Entries inside a Treeview cells (I am using Glade 3.6.7 and GTK+ 2.18.9 on Linux Cent OS 6.4 x86_64 and coding with Eclipse 3.6.1).

For the comboBoxes, I couldn't show them.

For the spin entries, I could show them and change their values but they aren't saved when I quit the cells. What I did is:

For comboBoxes:
- Add columns and rows for the treeview and assign a combo cellrenderer for the columns where I want to put comboBoxes.
- Create a comboBox model and assign it to the defined columns (I changed "Model" and "Text" properties)

For spin entries:
- Add columns and rows for the treeview and assign a spin cellrenderer for the columns where I want to put spin entries.
- Create an adjustment and assign it to the defined columns (I changed "Adjustment" and "Text" properties)

And here is the code that I used:

```
void on_addTreeRowButton_clicked (GtkButton *button, gpointer user_data)
{   
   addTreeEntry(NULL, NULL);
}

void addTreeviewEntry(gchararray comboBoxValue, guint spinEntryValue)
{
   GtkListStore *liststore;
   GtkTreeIter iter;
   //GtkComboBox *MsgTypeComboBox;

   liststore = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview)));
   gtk_list_store_append(liststore, &iter);
        gtk_list_store_set (liststore, &iter,
                            0, comboBoxValue,
                            1, spinEntryValue,
                            -1);
}
```